# Display count of element with function map() array

Tags: javascript

How will I display the number of elements in an array?

I have an array with the data which I receive from the server and display them in the table, I still need to display the list number in the element, say (1 - 'a', 2 - 'a', 3 - 'a').

I tried `map(size)`, but it didn’t help., How to solve such a simple task?

```
      {
          dashboards.vacancy && dashboards.vacancy.rating.map((data, index) => {
              return (
                  <Table.Row key={index}>
                      <Table.Cell>
                          <b>1</b> {data.position} - ${parseFloat(data.salary)} {data.shares_count  >= 1 ? '' : null } <a>[#]</a>
                      </Table.Cell>
                      <Table.Cell textAlign="right">{data.shares_count}</Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
              );
          })
      }
```

Comment: What does `dashboards.vacancy.rating` look like?

Comment: Just add `1` to the `index`

Comment: @Andreas - Oh, *that's* what they're asking, how to put a different number in the `<b>1.</b>` part. I didn't get that at first, thanks. @ Bavarius: As Andreas said, `index` will start at `0`, so: `<b>{index + 1}.</b>`.

Comment: @lurker [
  0: {shared_account_id: 1, shares_count: 1, position: "a", salary: "100"}
  1: {shared_account_id: 2, shares_count: 2, position: "b", salary: "200"}
];

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just add {index + 1} ?

Comment: @Bavarius - Yup. I edited my comment above a moment ago. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Great, thanks) sorry for such a stupid question

Comment: @Bavarius - No worries! Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot !